# Creating MetadataReference from in-memory assembly created with Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I have created an assembly, module and classes in a dynamic assembly using Reflection.Emit in .NET6. I unable to reference that assembly in my CSharpCompilation; I can't use MetadataReference.CreateFromFile as my assembly is in memory and has no location, and I can no longer use MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly as this has been depreciated.

How can I create a MetadataReference for this dynamic, in-memory assembly?